# Using async / await with mongoose.js

Tags: express, mongoose, async-await

Looking for help to rewrite these 2 queries using async / await instead of using the nested callbacks approach.

```
exports.post_edit_get = function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)){
        POST.findById(id, function (err, doc){
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            playerQuery.exec(function (err, players){
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                res.render('posts/posts_admin', { title: pageTitle, formData: doc, players: players });
            });
        });
    }else{
        res.send("Invalid ID");
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
const { isValid } = mongoose.Types.ObjectId

exports.post_edit_get = async function(req, res, next) {
    var { id } = req.params;

    if (!isValid(id)){
        return res.send("Invalid ID");        
    }

    try {
        const post = await POST.findById(id)
        const players = await playerQuery.exec()

        res.render('posts/posts_admin', { 
            title: pageTitle, 
            formData: doc, 
            players: players 
        })
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err)        
    }
}
```

If you want to get rid of these try/catches at the route handler level you'll want to have a look at this post; [Using async/await to write cleaner route handlers](https://itnext.io/using-async-await-to-write-cleaner-route-handlers-7fc1d91b220b)

Comment: Thank you.  I will test this out!